# bash shell tr -d -c options combination usage

Tags: bash, shell, tr

```
echo $PATH | tr -d -c :
```

this output is:

```
::::
```

The value of `$PATH` is:

```
/import/adams/2/z1/bin-pc.i86.linux:/import/adams/2/z1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

why I get such an output `;;;;`? I cannot understand -d -c :. -c option needs two sets, but -d needs only one set. which option is executed first? how does this result be generated?

Thanks.

Comment: right   should be ::::

Comment: I have modified it, mate.

Comment: `-c` needs only one set, `-d` is a switch and needs no set. See: `man tr`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ p=/import/adams/2/z1/bin-pc.i86.linux:/import/adams/2/z1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ echo "$p" |  tr -d -c :
::::
```

The `-d` option tells `tr` to *delete* characters.

The `-c` option says to use the *complement* of the character set that follows.

Because the character set which follows is `:`, everything *except* `:` is deleted.  That is why you see the output that you see.

#### More examples

In the following, the character set consists of not just `:` but also `/`.  Consequently, everything except `:` and `/` are deleted:

```
$ echo "$p" |  tr -d -c :/
/////://///:///://:/
```

In the following, we omit `-c` and specify a character set of `:`.  Consequently, all colons are deleted:

```
$ echo "$p" |  tr -d :
/import/adams/2/z1/bin-pc.i86.linux/import/adams/2/z1/bin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin
```

Comment: when we only use tr -c set1 set2, use set2 as complement of set1, right?so now only set1. I really want to now the order of execution of -d and -c. so -d process the result of -c or -c process the result of -d?

Comment: @Allen  `tr -c set1 set2` replaces _everything that is not in set1_ with set2.  `tr -d -c set1` deletes _everything that is not in set1_.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that you'd get `;` in your output and not `:`, but you're asking `tr` to `-d`elete everything that is in the `-c`omplement of `:`, so all non-: characters.

As `man 1 tr` says:

```
   -c, -C, --complement
          use the complement of SET1

   -d, --delete
          delete characters in SET1, do not translate
```

Comment: sorry it should be ::::

Comment: so why this combination can work out ::::

Comment: yep but -c still needs another set to do complement of :, now it doesn't have set2. I feel confused

Comment: @Allen: the universe in which the complement is taken is (always) implied.